Cast Count AS Integer
Unable to CAST comment_count AS integer: Says comment_count is not a column. To be specific I need to count the number of comments.article_id and label it as comment_count which needs to be an INTEGER.
SELECT COUNT (comments.article_id) AS comment_count, CAST(comment_count AS INTEGER)
     , articles.title, articles.topic, articles.author, articles.created_at, articles.votes,articles.article_img_url, articles.body, comments.article_id
FROM articles
JOIN comments ON articles.article_id = comments.article_id
WHERE articles.article_id = '1'
GROUP BY articles.title, articles.topic, articles.author, articles.created_at, articles.body, articles.votes,articles.article_img_url, comments.article_id;

Expecting the same output as:
SELECT COUNT (comments.article_id) AS comment_count
     , articles.title, articles.topic, articles.author, articles.created_at, articles.votes,articles.article_img_url, articles.body, comments.article_id
FROM articles
JOIN comments ON articles.article_id = comments.article_id
WHERE articles.article_id = '1'
GROUP BY articles.title, articles.topic, articles.author, articles.created_at, articles.body, articles.votes,articles.article_img_url, comments.article_id;

Except comment_count column needs to be a number not a string.

To be clear: comment_count is the result of COUNT (comments.article_id), which is type bigint if article_id is integer, or numeric if  article_id is something bigger. It's never a string.

You cannot refer to a column alias in the same SELECT list.
SELECT COUNT(comments.article_id) AS comment_count   -- alias defined here
     , CAST(comment_count AS INTEGER)                -- illegal reference !
...

On the same query level, you can only refer to input columns.
This would work:
SELECT COUNT(c.article_id)::int AS comment_count  -- cast right away
--   , CAST(comment_count AS INTEGER)             -- no need?
     , a.title, a.topic, a.author, a.created_at, a.votes,a.article_img_url, a.body, c.article_id
FROM   articles a
JOIN   comments c ON a.article_id = c.article_id
WHERE  a.article_id = '1'
GROUP  BY a.title, a.topic, a.author, a.created_at, a.body, a.votes,a.article_img_url, c.article_id;

... and can probably be optimized to this (using a correlated subquery):
SELECT (SELECT count(*)::int FROM comments c WHERE a.article_id = c.article_id) AS comment_count
     , a.title, a.topic, a.author, a.created_at, a.votes,a.article_img_url, a.body
--   , c.article_id  -- was dead freight, bound to be '1'
FROM   articles a
WHERE  a.article_id = '1';

Subtle difference: the last one retains articles in the result with 0 comments, which the other ones would eliminate.
About casting:

Cast syntax to convert a sum to float
Postgres data type cast

